# FSharp.Core: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: f#

**I have the following error when attempting to run a test:**

> {System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'FSharp.Core, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name:
>   'FSharp.Core, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
>   Register.RegisterResponse.__DebugDisplay()

**Tests.dll**

FSharp.Core: 3.1.2.5

Target F# runtime: 4.3.1.0

Target Framework: 4.6

Output type: Class Library

**ManageAccount.dll**

FSharp.Core: 3.1.2.5

Target F# runtime: 3.3.1.0

Target Framework: .NET Portable Subset (.Net Framework 4.5, ASP.Net Core 1.0, Windows 8)

Output type: Class Library

**I then added the following app config to my test project:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                          culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.2.5" newVersion="3.3.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

If I do need an app config, what value should my bindingRedirect be set to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.999.999.999" newVersion="3.3.1.0" />`. That's what most F# projects seem to be doing for FSharp.Core. (Or `newVersion="4.3.1.0"`, or even `newVersion="4.4.0.0"` if you upgrade to a newer FSharp.Core).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the newest version (`4.3.1.0` in this case) in `bindingRedirect/newVersion`, otherwise, you will probably get errors from code in `Tests.dll` assembly which relies on the newer version.

Alternatively you can update the reference in one of the assemblies (downgrade `Tests.dll` or upgrade `ManageAccount.dll`) so that they both use the same version.