# FsUnit: Unable to test portable library due to it and test project having different F#.Core versions

Tags: f#, nunit, fsunit

I have a Portable Library, for which the `FSharp.Core` version is `3.7.4.0`. Installing (in the Unit Test project) `FsUnit` installs, as a dependency, `FSharp.Core` version `3.1.2.5`.

Due to this, using the portable library's functions in my Unit Test project, for example:

```
module StammaTests.PieceTests

open Stamma
open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnitTyped

[<Test>]
let ``Testing a Basic function`` () =
    Piece.toChar Black King |> shouldEqual 'k'
```

yields error:

> Result Message:   System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=3.7.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Tried updating the `FSharp.Core` version from NuGet to `4.0.0.1` (even checking both projects when updating) and now even something simple like :

```
[<Test>]
let ``Testing the test`` () = 1 |> shouldEqual 1
```

doesn't work, giving this similar error.

> Result Message:   System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or
>   assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

And the error for the first failing test doesn't change.

I feel like I am missing something painfully obvious, and I found several people with similar problems, but I don't understand what they did to solve it (they all seem to have solved it ..) For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206991/fsharp-core-could-not-load-file-or-assembly).

## Edit

Both projects are libraries and I do not have an `app.config` file to add anything to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that actually worked [here](http://devcenter.wintellect.com/jwood/unit-testing-your-xamarin-forms-applications-with-f-and-fsunit)

Basically, adding an `App.config` to the **test** project, and writing the following:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.4.14350" newVersion="2.6.4.14350" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

It adds binding to *both* `Fsharp.Core` and `NUnit.Framework`, unlike the usual solutions where you only add a binding for `Fsharp.Core`.

Comment: So, the implication seems to be that FSharp.Core has a reference to nunit.framework. Is that the case? I ask because it seems odd.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I only put here what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add a binding redirect in your `app.config` file to redirect all `FSharp.Core` bindings to your desired version.  For example, to use version 4.4.0, your `app.config` file would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Which project should I add this to?

Comment: Just to be clear, both projects are libraries and I don't have an `app.config` file. I read this answer else where but as I don't have the file, I don't see how I can use it.

Comment: Just add a new app.config file to your library project

Comment: Couldn't get it work. I put `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="3.1.2.5" />` in my library , rebuit, and the same error. Different versions in the new versions didn't resolve it either.

Comment: Well, you didn't say anything about a binding failure for `nunit.framework`

Comment: I shared what I knew.