# F# How to setup FAKE project that can use FsUnit

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, f#-fake, fsunit

I'm trying to setup a basic FAKE F# project that can run FsUnit but I cannot figure out how to solve the `` Method not found: 'Void FsUnit.TopLevelOperators.should(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!!0,!!1>, !!0, System.Object)' `` errors.

I have read the following posts that seem to be related, but I'm apparently still not grokking it:

- [Main github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/789)
- [FSharp.Core packaging guidelines](https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html)
- [FsUnit unable to test portable library (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608983/fsunit-unable-to-test-portable-library-due-to-it-and-test-project-having-differ)
- [Another github issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsUnit/issues/23)

I have created a `JunkTest` library project with the following setup:

#### paket.dependencies

```
source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
nuget FAKE
nuget FSharp.Core
nuget FsUnit
nuget NUnit
nuget NUnit.Console
```

#### paket.references

```
FSharp.Core
FsUnit
NUnit
```

#### JunkTest.fs

```
module JunkTest

open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework

[<Test>]
let ``Example Test`` () =
    1 |> should equal 1               // this does not work
    //Assert.That(1, Is.EqualTo(1))   // this works (NUnit)
```

#### build.fsx (relevant part)

```
Target "Test" (fun _ ->
    !! (buildDir + "JunkTest.dll")
    |> NUnit3 (fun p ->
        {p with OutputDir = "TestResults" }
    )
)
```

### Output

I see that FSharp.Core.dll is being copied from the local `packages` directory:  `Copying file from "c:\Users\dangets\code\exercism\fsharp\dgt\packages\FSharp.Core\lib\net40\FSharp.Core.dll" to "c:\Users\dangets\code\exercism\fsharp\dgt\build\FSharp.Core.dll".`

And the nunit3-console execution:  `c:\Users\dangets\code\exercism\fsharp\dgt\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner\tools\nunit3-console.exe "--noheader" "--output=TestResults" "c:\Users\dangets\code\exercism\fsharp\dgt\build\JunkTest.dll"`

I have tried to add a `app.config` file with the in the test project root directory with the following but it doesn't seem to solve the issue (NOTE I am not using Visual Studio - do I need to do anything special for the project to include the `app.config` file?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** The solution was that I was not properly setting up the `App.config` file to get included in the build.  All of the answers that said "just add this to your `App.config` file" didn't help me because VSCode doesn't add this to the `fsproj` file automatically.

The part that I added is:

```
<None Include="App.config" />
```

In the `ItemGroup` that contains the other `<Compile Include=Foo.fs>` lines.

Comment: Is the `app.config` file included in the `fsproj` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MissingMethodException when testing a function that takes a function parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238316/missingmethodexception-when-testing-a-function-that-takes-a-function-parameter)

Comment: The problem was indeed with the `app.config` file - but what I couldn't find in that "duplicate" or elsewhere was how to properly include the `app.config` file in the build.  As I stated in the question I am *not* using Visual Studio so the information on it needing to be in the `fsproj` helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of `FSharp.Core` version mismatch. See, your application references one version of `FSharp.Core` and `FsUnit` references another version. This means that the `FSharpFunc<_,_>` type is going to be different (coming from different assemblies) for you and `FsUnit`, which in turn means that the `should` function exported by `FsUnit` is not the same function that your code is looking for, because it has a parameter of a different type.

This is where the `bindingRedirect` comes in. You're absolutely correctly added it to `app.config`, but from your question about whether you're doing it correctly, I get a suspicion that you might not. The thing with `app.config` is, it's not actually the program configuration. Rather, it's the *source code* for program configuration. At compile time, this file gets copied to `bin\Debug\Your.Project.dll.config`, and only then it will get picked up at runtime. If you didn't add this file to the `fsproj` project file (which, I suspect, might be the case), then it's not getting copied to the right place during build, and thus isn't getting picked up at runtime.

Another reason for it still not working may be that you've specified an incorrect version of `FSharp.Core` in your `app.config` file. Which brings me to the next point.

Crafting that file by hand is a bit fragile: when you upgrade `FSharp.Core` to a new version (or Paket does it for you), you may forget to fix it in `app.config` and even if you don't, it's a bit of a hassle. But Paket can help you with that: if you add the [`redirects: on` options](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/dependencies-file.html#Redirects-option) to your `paket.dependencies` file, Paket will add the `bindingRedirect` cruft to your `app.config` automatically:

```
source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
nuget FAKE
nuget FSharp.Core redirects: on
nuget FsUnit
nuget NUnit
nuget NUnit.Console
```

Comment: You were right with me not properly setting up the `App.config` file in the `fsproj`.  It is working now - though I will have to read up more on the paket redirects: on.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an FSharp.Core version mismatch.

The NuGet package you're using ships with FSharp.Core 4.4 (not 4.3.1).  I recommend modifying your binding redirect to use 4.4:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
```